# Periodic Functions of Cycle greater than two.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I am now aware of periodic functions, and how they cycle like binary flags. It helps to use this in discrete math.

This brings me to my problem. I am trying to make a function that is periodic for cycles more than two. I have been using $asin^2(z\pi/2) + bcos^2(z\pi/2)$ for cycles of legnth two, and can't seem to alternate them in sets of three with 0's in between. To be more specific, it will give a particular value once every three integers and another particular value in the other cases. In the case with periodic size two it would give the value $a$ and $b$ alternately. However instead I need something along the lines of, if x is an integer $f(x) = 4$ for every $n$th term and $f(x) = 0$ for the others. For $n=3$ the cycle would go $4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, \dots$

-TJL

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason not to definying the function in the following way
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
4 \text{ if $x=3k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
0 \text{ elsewhere}.
\end{cases}\quad?
$$

*Edit:* A new version for the expected continuous case.

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
4-4x& \text{ for $0\leq x\leq1$}\\
0 &\text{ for $1\leq x\leq2$}\\
4x-8 &\text{ for $2\leq x\leq3$}.
\end{cases}
$$
This function, repeated in the obvious way, is continuous and has the desired property. As far as I understand your future applications, its approximation by its Fourier series will be useful for you.

Comment: Yes there is a reason. I want to convert functions of that discrete form into a continuous function, and cure my casual obsession of an unsolved problem. As of right now I am using the floor function for values on trigonometry functions that don't quite reach 1, however there must exist a better solution.

Comment: @TJLockwood OK. I will remove my answer in a while. However I would suggest adding the continuity assumption in your question, because now my answer is correct, but completely useless.

Comment: I was thinking it might be Fourier Series involved too. I need to learn more about this topic. Plus I appreciate the piecewise approximation that just might work.